# SELECT data via array from different tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

hello guys i found some similar questions here  but nothing work's for me  maybe someone can help me.
i have a couple of filter where the user can list other users by properties like in a dating site. i want to show the user just the members from the filters the user choose.  i store the keywords in an array and want to get the data now from two different tables. 
at the moment i use this query but its just shows me the values from one table

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username IN ($data) AND country IN ($data) OR city IN ($data) OR gender IN ($data)";
```

i need to get some more properties like smoker or non smoker etc. from another table  how would i do this with this array ($data). sorry for the bad english

the table one is users who contains  id, username, gender, country
and the other table called properties who contains  id, userid, hobbies, jobs  i need to join them somehow

Comment: Show us your other tables and columns, it will be easier.

Comment: What is the value of $data?

Comment: the value of $data is depending on users choice for example france,footbal,male,......,....... or just football,male  the user should find people by his search results

Comment: Write all your php code if you want some help.

Comment: thanks  its working now with a bit of modifying based on your code thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JOIN` on their "linked" column :

```
$sql  = " SELECT u.username, u.country  ";
$sql .= " FROM users u ";
$sql .= " LEFT OUTER JOIN other_table t ON u.id = t.id";
$sql .= " WHERE username IN ($data) AND country IN ($data) OR city IN ($data) OR gender IN ($data)";
```

[MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).

Comment: thanks for the quick reply but i get just Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in...  i edit my question.  thanks anyway